# Listener to check internet availability in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When there is a internet availability in mobile i need an event to be triggerd to push offline data in mobile to webservice. How to do this in xamarin forms or native xamarin?
Battery usage should be also be considered.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms, you can use the connectivity plugin. It allows you to subscribe to a connectivity changed event.

[Details here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/ConnectivityChanges.html)